# how to Group By LINQ Query result to DataGridView without looping

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I Have a list "listemp" :

```
id  |  name  |  age |  departement
----|--------|------|----------
1   |  name1 |  22  | 1
2   |  name2 |  33  | 3
3   |  name3 |  20  | 1
4   |  name4 |  25  | 2
5   |  name5 |  22  | 1
6   |  name6 |  25  | 2
```

I want to group by departement 
the result must be like that :

```
id  |  name  |  age |  departement
----|--------|------|----------
1   |  name1 |  22  | 1
3   |  name3 |  20  | 1
5   |  name5 |  22  | 1
4   |  name4 |  25  | 2
6   |  name6 |  25  | 2
2   |  name2 |  33  | 3
```

My code is :

```
var db = from item in listemp group item by item.departement;
dgv.columns.add("0","id");
dgv.columns.add("1","name");
dgv.columns.add("2","age");
dgv.columns.add("3","departement");
foreach(var i in db)
{
   foreach(var c in i)
   {
    dgv.rows.add(c.id , c.name , c.age , c.departement)
   }
}
```

this code is work perfectly but I want another methode to do that without looping

Comment: Your desired result does not look "grouped" at all, it seems you only want to "sort". Why do you `group` here at all?

Comment: thank you for your answer yes i know but i wanna do it by group because the teacher ask us this methode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution without looping

```
var db = from item in listitem group item by item.departement into g from i in g select i
```